# Jquery ajax call when browser back button is pressed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am busy creating a store in Codeigniter / PhP / Jquery.
The problem I have is when the user adds items to the cart, and presses the browser's back button, It returns to the previous state before the items were added to the cart.

I have tried putting another ajax call in a jquery `$(function() {});` block, but this does not run when the back button is pressed.

Is it possible to do this or should I try to find another solution, perhaps a function to refresh the cart that will run every 10 seconds?

Thanx in advance

Comment: where is your code? where do you save cart items? haw do you trigger your Ajax call? do you use the current session ?

Comment: the cart items will be saved in the database and will be triggered when the user clicks tha "Add to cart" button, so every time the page is refreshed or every 10 seconds, there should be a function that will trigger another "getCart" function

Comment: the function still has to be written, but the normal document.ready does not work when the back button is pressed, so I first want to know if there is a way

Comment: okay so you just need a way to detect back button on the browser to trigger your function r8 ?

Comment: yes, but after the previous page is being shown, so first go back to the previous page and then test if button has been pressed

Comment: or I can try to force the page to reload when it is pressed, but then the user might not see it loading again and continues

Comment: No don't do that, AJAX was created to solve this in the first place, btw have you tried window.history.pushState to detect back button ?

Comment: I changed my code a bit with jQuery's "onload" function and it seems to be showing in the console when I say console,log, so think if it does this it will run the AJAX call again, will keep you posted